# Showing rows with greatest count of a specific value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query:

```
select 
    d.sdealer_number
    ,c.icontract_term
    ,case when (c.icontract_term / 12) = 0 THEN cast(c.icontract_term as varchar) + ' M' ELSE cast((c.icontract_term / 12) as varchar) + ' Y' END as Term
    ,count(c.icontract_term) as [Count]
from dealers d
inner join contracts c on c.sdealer_number = d.sdealer_number
where d.sdealer_number not like '%demo%'
group by c.icontract_term, d.sdealer_number
order by d.sdealer_number
```

Which returns this result set:

```
sdealer_number  icontract_term  Term    Count
DL00001             84  7 Y 3
DL00001             12  1 Y 12
DL00001             48  4 Y 15
DL00001             60  5 Y 2
DL00001             24  2 Y 2
DL00001             3   3 M 1
DL00001             6   6 M 5
DL00001             36  3 Y 1
DL00002             84  7 Y 4
DL00002             48  4 Y 2
DL00002             6   6 M 35
DL00002             3   3 M 8
DL00002             12  1 Y 8
DL00002             36  3 Y 2
DL00007             36  3 Y 1
DL00007             12  1 Y 1
DL00007             60  5 Y 4
DL00007             24  2 Y 2
DL00007             48  4 Y 9
DL00007             84  7 Y 1
```

I need to filter the result set and only show rows where `4 Y` (48 month term) and `5 Y` (60 month term) are the majority of contracts sold.

So, in the above example `DL00001` should not show up nor should `DL00002`, but `DL00007` should show up because they have more `4-5 Y` terms contracts sold than any other contract type they sell.

---

EDIT:

Here is solution used with credit going to @MWillemse:

```
; with t as (select d.sdealer_number, sum(case when c.icontract_term in (48,60) then 1 else 0 end) as '4-5 Yeam Term', sum(case when c.icontract_term not in (48,60) then 1 else 0 end) as 'Non 4-5 Yeam Term'
from dealers d
inner join contracts c on c.sdealer_number = d.sdealer_number
where d.sdealer_number not like '%demo%'
group by d.sdealer_number)
select * from t
where t.[4-5 Yeam Term] > t.[Non 4-5 Yeam Term]
order by sdealer_number
```

Comment: row_number() will get you there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by you dealer_number and conditionally sum the counts using a construct like this: `SUM(CASE WHEN Term IN ( '4 Y', '5 Y' ) THEN [Count] ELSE 0 END)` and use a having clause to filter which groups to keep.

**EDIT:** After rereading your query I realize you need to filter the results, not group them altogether. The query below will probably better suit your needs.

```
WITH    
YourOriginalQuery
    AS (SELECT    d.sdealer_number
                , c.icontract_term
                , CASE WHEN (c.icontract_term / 12) = 0 THEN CAST(c.icontract_term AS VARCHAR) + ' M'
                        ELSE CAST((c.icontract_term / 12) AS VARCHAR) + ' Y'
                END AS Term
                , COUNT(c.icontract_term) AS [Count]
        FROM      dealers d
        INNER JOIN contracts c ON c.sdealer_number = d.sdealer_number
        WHERE     d.sdealer_number NOT LIKE '%demo%'
        GROUP BY  c.icontract_term
                , d.sdealer_number
        ) ,
Totals
    AS (SELECT    YOQ.*
                , Y45Total = SUM(CASE WHEN Term IN ('4 Y', '5 Y') THEN 1
                                    ELSE 0
                                END) OVER (PARTITION BY dealer_number)
                , NY45Total = SUM(CASE WHEN Term NOT IN ('4 Y', '5 Y') THEN 1
                                        ELSE 0
                                END) OVER (PARTITION BY dealer_number)
        FROM      YourOriginalQuery AS YOQ
        )
SELECT *
FROM   Totals
WHERE  Totals.Y45Total > Totals.NY45Total
ORDER BY  d.sdealer_number
```

Comment: I liked this one.  It made me rethink my original query in a different way.  I will edit my original answer with the solution I used.  But I still credit it to you.  I've never used the `SUM(case` before and it made it much easier to rethink.